# bsd sed replace hex values in file

Tags: sed, hex, bsd

Using GNU Sed i'm able to replace some hex value using the following command

`gsed 's/.*\xFF\xD8/\xFF\xD8/g' myfile`

I'm on OSX, so the default `sed` is the BSD one. Unfortunately the previous command does not work the BSD `sed`.

Any idea why this and how to do what i'm looking for : removing everything before a FFD8 value in my file.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to deal with that problem is to use `bash`'s ['ANSI-C Quoting'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism:

```
sed $'s/.*\xFF\xD8/\xFF\xD8/g' myfile
```

Note that \xFF\xD8 is not valid UTF-8, so you may have problems with the characters, but the basic mechanism works:

```
$ echo sed $'s/.*\xFF\xD8/\xFF\xD8/g' | odx
0x0000: 73 65 64 20 73 2F 2E 2A FF D8 2F FF D8 2F 67 0A   sed s/.*../../g.
0x0010:
$
```

`odx` is a hex dump program.